# Get extracted size from tgz before extracting

Tags: bash, tar

Is it possible to get the size that a tgz will take up once it's extracted, but without extracting it? I basically want

```
tar tzf file.tgz
```

with sizes beside them. I'm really looking for a total, so a solution that gives total size but not specific file sizes would work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it compressed using gzip compression, you can do something like:

```
gunzip -l filename.tar.gz
```

Since a tar is not compressed, that should give you the information you need.

Comment: Hm, to easy ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Hm I would prefer something like:

```
tar vtzf somefile.tar.gz |awk '{SUM += $3} END {print SUM}'
```

Comment: This is the closest to correct. Ideally you would round each $3 up to the filesystem block size. Variations in filesystems make this very difficult to solve in general. At least awk '{SUM+=($3>512?$3:512)}END{print SUM}' - but if you know the filesystem blocksize (if there is one), replace 512 with the actual blocksize.

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat file.tgz | wc -c
```

Will give you the number of characters taken up by the uncompressed .tar file, which will be very close to correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm finding everything sites in the web, and don't resolve this problem the get size when file size is  bigger of 4GB.

first, which is most faster?

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time zcat oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | wc -c
    6667028480

    real    0m45.761s
    user    0m43.203s
    sys     0m5.185s
```

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time gzip -dc oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | wc -c
    6667028480

    real    0m45.335s
    user    0m42.781s
    sys     0m5.153s
```

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz
    -rw-r--r-- oracle/oinstall 111828 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.log
    -rw-r----- oracle/oinstall 6666911744 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.dmp

    real    0m46.669s
    user    0m44.347s
    sys     0m4.981s
```

definitely, **tar -xvf** is the most faster, but
¿how to cancel executions after get header?

**my solution is this**:

```
[oracle@base tmp]$  time echo $(timeout --signal=SIGINT 1s tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | awk '{print $3}') | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
    6667023572
```